# How to reference an array item in an object array? Js

Tags: javascript, arrays

sorry if this question seems a little stupid but I have the following code:

```
var sides = {
    'red': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'ora': [0,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,0],
    'yel': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'gre': [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
    'blu': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'whi': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
}
```

As an example how can I reference array item [0] in sides['red'] ?

I have tried:

```
sides['red'][0];
sides['red'[0]];
```

This is probably very wrong, can anyone suggest how I would declare it otherwise?

Comment: The first one should work.

Comment: `sides['red'][0];` should be fine ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first trial works as intended:

```
sides['red'][0];
```

This returns `0` as the first value (the `0` index) in your `slides['red']` array is equal to `0`:

```
'red': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], ...
        ^
```

You could also use:

```
slides.red[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it must be my logic that isn't working and not the reference :S

Answer (score 1):

Simple you can use `.` operator:

```
sides.red[0]
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hz6rrq5p/)

```js
var sides = {
    'red': [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'ora': [0,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,0],
    'yel': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'gre': [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
    'blu': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    'whi': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
}

alert(sides['red'][0]);
alert(sides.red[0]);
```